# How can we separate the Reports and tools into equal parts of that row?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

Hi all,
In this image i want to separate the reports and tools sections as like in the account home page. how can i achieve in my custom VF page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using html and css.

You can use the below code.

```
<html>
<div style="float:left;width:40%">
Reports
</div>
<div style="float:right;width:40%">
Tools
</div>
</html>
```